# Cannot find type converter when converting json object?

Tags: json, kotlin

I will use a type converter to convert the json object that came with my request, but it was used in the library, but now it cannot be found. Is there a different way to do this?

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.animsh.itunessearch.models.ITunesResponse
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken


class ResultTypeConverter {

    var gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun responseToString(Response: Response): String {
        return gson.toJson(Response)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToResponse(data: String): Response {
        val listType = object : TypeToken<Response>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(data, listType)
    }
}
```

import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
In the section, TypeToken cannot be found, so it appears as red.

Answer (score 0):

you might have a missing dependency in your module gradle file.
Check if the following line is in it.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

`TypeToken` belongs to this dependency

Comment: implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6' I was using this version, I checked again, but it already exists.